# How to get the Name of View in Java Class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a class, I am passing `EditText` to it. There are more than 10 EditBox in my activity, I pass each to my class. In my class i need to add conditions based on the name of EditBox; For example,

if `EditBox` is of `Address` type, then i need to user to enter at least 5 characters in the `EditBox`

if `EditBox` is of `Name` type, then i need to user to enter at least 7 characters in the `EditBox`

So i need to know the name of EditBox in my class, Kindly tell me a way to get name of `EditBox` in Java Class

```
  formTextCosmetics.validateInputFields(etName, ivWarningCardName);

  formTextCosmetics.validateInputFields(etAddress, ivWarningAddress);
```

**Java Class**

```
     public void validateInputFields(final EditText editText, final ImageView imageView){

            editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus){
                if(editText.getText().toString().trim().length() ==0){
                //Here i need to check the name of editText
```

Comment: And what do you mean exactly by "name" of your `EditText`? Its `id`?

Comment: You can check for its id

Comment: And if, for some reason, you can't check based on id, you can make use of the View.setTag(Object) to set whatever arbitrary meta data you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add validations in XML file.

```
<EditText      
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
android:maxLength="30"
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLine="1"
/>
```

You can also use a textwatcher to check min and max length.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     int length= s.getText.ToString().Trim().Length();
     if (length<5){
     s.setError("Any message")
}
}
```